# Convert CHARINDEX in sql query to LINQ using LAMBDA Expression

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have a SQL query which I am trying to convert to Linq using Lambda expression.
I was able to do a normal join operation ON TABLE1.XR_ID AND TABLE2.ID but then I realized that the SQL query is joining on CHARINDEX. I did some research but I wasn't able to find out any resource leading me in right direction.

SQL:

```
SELECT  distinct a.XR_ID FROM 
TABLE1 a 
JOIN  TABLE2 b ON CHARINDEX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), a.XR_ID), CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), B.ID), 1) = 1
WHERE 
b.TYPE = 'Q'
```

LINQ:

```
var innerQuery =  
             context.TABLE1.
             Join(context.TABLE2, 
             table1 => table1.XR_ID, 
             table2=> table2.ID, 
             (table1 , table2) => 
               new 
               { 
                TABLE1 = table1 , 
                TABLE2 = table2
               })
              .Where( y=> y.table2.TYPE == "Q")
              .Distinct()
              .ToList();
```

The above query is not giving me the same result as the sql query. Can any one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate `CHARINDEX` using [`SqlFunctions` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `CharIndex` method, but I don't think you can do your `something = 1` join condition in LINQ.

I think you should do cross join and move your condition to `where` clause. That's why I would start from following:

```
var innerQuery = from t1 in context.Table1
                 from t2 in context.Table2
                 where SqlFunctions.CharIndex(
                           SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)table1.XR_ID),
                           SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)table2.ID)) == 1
                     && t2.Type == "Q"
                 select new { Table1 = t1, Table2 = t2 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Let me give this a try..But I think this looks like a valid alternative.

Comment: nope.. It give me the same list of result as my LINQ expressing ..its not giving the result in the sql query.

Comment: What results? Is there an error? Have you tried checking generated SQL statement?

Comment: There is no error..its just the list the sql result has 1616 records and our result has 1252..

Comment: Have you tried checking generated SQL statement? Do you apply `Dictinct` somewhere later to your join `innerQuery`?

Comment: I do apply distinct but I an doing tht in both the sql and the LINQ query...Let add the generate sql and try ..